# Flutter - using dynamic functions to control UI

Tags: function, flutter, dart, dynamic

This one seems really simply conceptually, but doesn't exist in any of the beginner guides I'm reading through. Basically I'm wanting to dynamically change my UI based on user input, as test I set up a function outside of this:

```
testFunction(){
  return Container(
    child: Text(
        "Hello World"
    ),
  );
}

dynamic outputType1 = testFunction;
```

...with the intention of having multiple versions of this that could do different layouts, and then later on I simply want to call this:

```
  Container(
    color:Colors.grey[400],
    padding:EdgeInsets.all(40),
    child: Text("Please select cards",
      style:TextStyle(
          fontFamily:'Amatic',
          fontSize:30,
          fontWeight:FontWeight.bold
      ),
    ),
  ),
  outputType1,
```

I get an error regarding type setting but I can't work out if I'm close to fixing it or if I the above code fundamentally does not work.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: you should change the outputType1 to Widget outputType1 = testFunction;

Comment: Last line should be `outputType1(),`

Comment: There's all sorts of type can't be type errors that Android Studio is throwing up, not sure if it's because of that - I can however bury the different widgets within a master widget and control the variable from that but not as elegant in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have type Widget in your build function. Change the type of outputType1 to Widget and you'll be fine.

```
Widget testFunction(){
  return Container(
    child: Text(
        "Hello World"
    ),
  );
}

Widget Function() outputType1 = testFunction;
```

and call the function in your build function

```
    Container(
      color:Colors.grey[400],
      padding:EdgeInsets.all(40),
      child: Text("Please select cards",
      style:TextStyle(
          fontFamily:'Amatic',
          fontSize:30,
          fontWeight:FontWeight.bold
      ),
    ),
  ),
  outputType1(),
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I've just got a chance to test this and the declaration throws an error "A value of type dynamic function can’t be assigned to a variable of type widget".Thanks though.

Comment: @SimonKwong Thanks for trying it out. I just edited my answer and added some change on declaring the testFunction. Could you try it out again?

Comment: Just tried but get the message - dynamic can't be assigned to widget functions, seems like it just can't be possible to do it this way.

Comment: @SimonKwong Are you calling outputType1 inside a column or row? I tried this code myself and it worked. Are you sure you copied and pasted my code to your project?

Comment: Actually worked it out the line "Widget Function() outputType1 = testFunction;" has to be moved to be inside my main widget... the error was saying I can only initialise static functions outside of it, no idea what that means really but works now. Thannks btw!

Comment: @SimonKwong I'm glad you got it working! It would be great if you could accept my answer!

Comment: Haha sorry, this is how much of a newb I am, I upvoted it and thought I accepted... thanks again :)